# How to display a data with 0 value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named tbllog, it's field is type, userid, action, datelog. The userid is a foreign key coming from tbluser. some userid in my tbllog is 0 and i can't seem to display it using these query.

```
SELECT * FROM tbllog INNER JOIN tbluser ON (tbluser.userid = tbllog.userid)
```

It does display a rows consist of non-zero userid. My question is how to display all the data from tbllog whether the userid is 0 or not?

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. :)

Comment: Also this is worth reading to understand difference between joins: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: Thanks @DmitryP. I'll read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT * FROM tbllog 
LEFT JOIN tbluser 
ON tbluser.userid = tbllog.userid
```

For More Info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Thanks sir. Can I marked this as an answer? @Gordon already answered it in comment.